# angular material => Form validation except one conditional field

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

In my angular form , i have one select field which takes yes/no values, and another filed which appears only if user select "yes". Html code is as below,

```
<form [formGroup]="Form">
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Is Permitted</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="perm" [formControl]="permission" required>
        <mat-option value="No">No</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Yes">Yes</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="form-element" *ngIf="perm=='Yes'">
    <input matInput placeholder="Pass Number" formControlName="passnum" required autocomplete="off">
    <mat-error *ngIf="passnum.touched && !passnum.required">
        Pass Number is required.
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="Save();" [disabled]="!Form.form.valid">SAVE</button>
```

This is working but the problem is with SAVE button. As i want the button enabled only if form is in valid state but if user select No, the second field is not shown and form is not valid , hence SAVE button is not enabled. Technically the second field validation should be considered only if it is Shown.

My fields are simple created as

```
permission: new FormControl('No'),
passnum: new FormControl()
```

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: You could use `[required]="perm=='Yes'"` in the `input` tag

Comment: I added this, but doesn't work. <mat-form-field class="form-element" [required]="perm=='Yes'" *ngIf="perm=='Yes'">. Throws error Can't bind to 'required' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-form-field'.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: See the last part of my comment, "... in the **input tag**". Not the mat-form-field tag.

Comment: My Mistake. It worked when i selected "yes" but throws error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'disabled: false'. Current value: 'disabled: true'" for button. And does not enable SAVE button when i change value from "yes" to "no"

Answer (score 0):

Where you create the form, the logic can look like the following. The reason the form is invalid is because you have made the second field required regardless of the first field.

@Igor's comment could work if the second field is required if and only if the first field is yes.

```
private buildForm(): void {
    this.yourForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      permission: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      passNum:: ['']
    });
```